# I am trying to make a simple login form with reactjs, axios and spring boot and axios post is not working

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I am trying to make a simple login form with reactjs, axios and spring boot
This is the code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';


function UserLogin() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  // const [user, setUser] = useState({
  //   email: '',
  //   password : '',
  // })

  function handelSubmit(event){

    const user ={
      email: email,
      password : password,
    }
      // alert(user.email)    // "it shows the user email"
      axios.post("http://15ed-2405-201-e039-600a-fd16-d1c2-84e-cff1.ngrok.io/authenticate",user)
      .then((response) => {
        alert(user.email)   //"does not work"
       if(response.data!=null){
         alert('login');
         console.log(response.data);
       }
       else{
         alert('failed');
       }
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <div className='login'>
      <form className='login-form'>
        <input type='email' placeholder='Email' value={email}  onChange = {(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}></input>
        <input type='password' placeholder='Password' value={password}  onChange = {(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button type='submit' className='btn__submit' onClick={handelSubmit}>Submit</button>      
      </form>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default UserLogin
```

Ive used spring boot for the backend.
calling alert above axios line works fine but if I alert(user.email) inside axios it does not works and also it is not sending any data. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: When you say that it "does not work", what exactly do you mean? What's the error? Is the data undefined? Is the request going through and returning a bad response code? Please provide more information about the exact problem.  My initial guess is that the `axios.post` call is scoped, and doesn't have knowledge of the outside function variable `user`. What does the `response` contain?